# Why doesn't Sinch allow keeping messages for longer than 30 days

Tags: ios, xcode, sinch

On their documentation they specify that "Users can keep a 30-day message history". I assume this means that after 30 days the messages are deleted,is there anyway of extending this or disabling this feature?

Answer (score 0):

We should change the word history, we store the message for delivery for 30 days. There is not really an inbox with sinch, its a delivery process so every message will be stored for 30 days to be delivered to all the users devices.